# Add spinner to HashMap Android

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView, and the list view is populated with an HashMap. I can add text without in issue. I have an issue adding spinners.

How would I go about adding spinners to a HashMap in Android?

Here is the code for my HashMap:

```
        final Spinner hashSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);
    hashSpinner.setAdapter(hashSpinner);



    mapTwo = new HashMap<String, String>();

    mapTwo.put("zero", "OK");
    mapTwo.put("one", " 2");
    mapTwo.put("two", " 3");
    listTwo.add(mapTwo);

    try {
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listOne, R.layout.row_two,
                new String[] { "zero", "one", "two" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.spinner1, R.id.spinner2, R.id.spinner3 });
        listViewOne.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

row_two already contains the spinners, the issue is, I can't get it to display. How will I go about adding the spinners to the ListView?

Comment: Try overriding your adapter's `getView` method and populate the spinner there.

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);
    hashSpinner.setAdapter(hashSpinner); ... no errors here??